# Why is my button element not created as a child in my parent div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, parent-child, appendchild

I have the following code. I want to add a button as a child of another element named `element`.

```js
//parent div
const element = document.getElementById("idClass")

const button = document.createElement("button")

button.textContent = "Click me"

element.appendChild("button")
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work ?

Comment: `element.appendChild("button")` -> `element.appendChild(button)` because `"button"` is a string, `button` is a variable which holds an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the Javascript code into the `window.onload()` function.
Below is the working example for the same.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    var element = document.getElementById("idClass");
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = "Click me";
    element.appendChild(button);
}
```

```html
<div id="idClass"></div>
```

Comment: This has little to do with the real problem, which is just that they put the variable in quotes.

Comment: Yes, only the minor mistake is you have placed the button variable as a string. remaining is good.